# How to cast with additional bounds inside generic type parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism, multiple-bounds

Is it possible to cast an object to fit an argument that is both a generic type parameter and with multiple bounds?

The situation i have is like the following:

```
public <T extends TypeA & TypeB> void problematic(Class<T> class)
{
    doSomething();
}

public void myMethod(Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof TypeA && obj instanceof TypeB)
    {
        problematic(obj.getClass())
    }
}
```

The problematic method works fine if i have a specific Class that implements both interfaces.
The problem is this time, i only have an Object to work with and must cast it to satisfy the compiler.

The method problematic is already used a lot and i whould prefer to not change it.

I already tried the following casts:

```
problematic(obj.getClass())
problematic((Class<TypeA & TypeB>) obj.getClass())
problematic((Class<? extends TypeA & TypeB>) obj.getClass())
problematic((Class<?>) obj.getClass())
problematic((Class<(TypeA & TypeB)>) obj.getClass())
problematic((Class<TypeC>) obj.getClass())
```

TypeC implements TypeA and TypeB, but the Object is not actual implementing TypeC and therefore while this compiles it just fails at runtime

Comment: "but the Object is not actual implementing TypeC and therefore while this compiles it just fails at runtime" Are you *sure*? What's the exception that is thrown at runtime?

Comment: @Sweeper The Exception i get is java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.path.path$TestClass cannot be cast to class org.path.path$TypeC
I was guessing that's because TestClass doesn't implement TypeC or its methods

Comment: Are you casting to `TypeC` or `Class<TypeC>`? The error says you are casting to `TypeC`, but `problematic` takes a `Class`.

Comment: @Sweeper I've gone away from my real problem and tried the TypeC solution in a new enviroment, where it actually worked. Something in my code must make it invalid. Maybe because TypeC extends a lot more interfaces, or because TypeC doesn't have any methods in my encapsulated test. However, if i can't use my existing types, this is not a feasible way to go for me, especially since i found another way to do it. But thanks for the help, you got me to my current solution

Answer (score 0):

### Raw Types

After a lot of trial and error, i found a solution by using raw types:

```
problematic((Class) obj.getClass())
```

This will give a rawtypes warning, but it works, and since the cast is checked beforehand, there's no real issue to add a @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") to the cast.

Still, this looks more like a workaround and i wonder why declaring something like Class<TypeA & TypeB> is not an option.